# How to insert data into 2 tables simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 data tables in my database. One database is named as Employee_Data. Employee_Data has 3 columns named such as id , name , contact .  The Second data table name is Employee_Achievements which has another 3 columns such as Achievement_Name , Marks , Grade.

I want to insert data into both these data tables in one SQL statement. Which is the best way ? please provide SQL query examples

Comment: This is not possible in standard SQL as far as I know, though there are vendor specific ways.  It is easy to with two statements in a transaction or a stored procedure.  Why do you need it in a single statement?

Comment: @Nilaksha Perera try with a transaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Barry said, creating a transaction is the only way. SQL Engine takes care of the coupling of the data within the transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO Employee_Data (Name, Contact)
VALUES ('X', 'Y')
DECLARE @id as int = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO Employee_Achievements (EmployeeId, Achievement_Name , Marks , Grade)
VALUES ( (@id, 'A1', 'M1', 'G1'), (@id, 'A2', 'M2', 'G2') )
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```